# Keep only one UIButton highlighted?

Tags: ios, uibutton, highlight

I have a table of UIButton :

```
UIButton *buttons [16];
```

What I want to do is to keep only one button highlighted if it's pushed.

I create, initialize them in a loop :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++)
{
    // Initializing the buttons...
    [self performSelector:@selector(buttonSelected:) withObject:buttons[i] afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Then :

```
- (void)buttonSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            buttons[i].highlighted = NO;
        }];
    }
    [self doHighlight:sender];
}

- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        b.highlighted = YES;
    }];
}
```

But it doesn't work, this only highlights the last (16th) button and keeps it always highlighted.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Make tag for your button's. And check tag if it's 20 for example highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your buttonSelected to become:

```
- (void)buttonSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            buttons[i].highlighted = NO;
            if(sender == buttons[i])[self doHighlight:sender];
       }];
    }
}
```